# Jogar Valores de um DataGridView para outro DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Boa noite galera, estou com um problema. Eu tenho um datagridview que é conectado com o banco. Eu fis um filtro nesse grid normal. Agora eu quero pegar os valores filtrados desse grid e jogar em outro grid Normal, criado na mão sem conecção com banco.
Resumindo quero transportar os valores de um grid para outro grid.

Help-me.

Comment: Você fez algum código?

Comment: não, porque não faço ideia de como faz.

Comment: Pensei em usar um for pegando a qtd de registro do grid filtrado e em cada posicao do for popular a msm linha no outro grid.

Comment: Você disse que fez o filtro no primeiro e tudo certo? correto?

Comment: correto, o filtro no primeiro deu certo, agora so falta pegar os dados que ficaram no filtro, e jogar em outro grid

Comment: olha só é igualar um no outro tipo `dataGridView2.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource` já tentou...!

Comment: Pronto deu certo... Bem facil mais pra quem não tem experiencia e não conhece o codigo fica meio dificil rsrs. Muito obrigadoVirgilio me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Codigo correto:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource
```

Comment: isso foi a solução pro seu problema ?

Comment: Foi Sim, simples mais eu não sabia rsrs!

Comment: marque como resposta para finalizar a questão